# VB 2010 how to control an elementhost by a button in a Form1.vb

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

am trying to start an animation that i have in an elemnthost1 by a button that I placed in a Form1.vb

The Elementhost has already a working button included which is working but I need basically to click it by clicking a Form.vb button

Button in the Element host need too be clicked by clicking the button Start in the Form or which would be even better just start the animation by clicking Start Button in the Form.vb

I have been trying to figure this out but i am not able to do that

Thanks
Ste
here is my xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" Height="372" Width="640">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <PathGeometry x:Key="Daytona">
            <PathFigure IsClosed="True" StartPoint="290,320">
                <ArcSegment Point="290,320" Size="10,10" SweepDirection="Counterclockwise"></ArcSegment>
                <ArcSegment Point="430,250" Size="200,75"></ArcSegment>
                <ArcSegment Point="400,225" Size="30,25"></ArcSegment>
                <ArcSegment Point="370,215" Size="200,200" SweepDirection="Clockwise" ></ArcSegment>
                <ArcSegment Point="320,207" Size="150,200"></ArcSegment>
                <BezierSegment Point1="305,207" Point2="230,200" Point3="295,175"></BezierSegment>
                <ArcSegment Point="420,175" Size="570,500" SweepDirection="Clockwise"></ArcSegment>
                <BezierSegment Point1="437,177" Point2="452,162" Point3="462,152"></BezierSegment>
                <BezierSegment Point1="470,140" Point2="555,75" Point3="527,140"></BezierSegment>
                <ArcSegment Point="455,210" Size="500,500" SweepDirection="Clockwise"></ArcSegment>
                <BezierSegment Point1="445,220" Point2="450,280" Point3="545,220"></BezierSegment>
                <ArcSegment Point="480,18" Size="120,115"></ArcSegment>
                <ArcSegment Point="270,17" Size="520,100"></ArcSegment>
                <BezierSegment Point1="260,17" Point2="250,15" Point3="228,34"></BezierSegment>
                <BezierSegment Point1="218,34" Point2="200,33" Point3="180,20"></BezierSegment>
                <ArcSegment Point="40,220" Size="140,121"></ArcSegment>
                <ArcSegment Point="290,320" Size="690,600"></ArcSegment>
            </PathFigure>
        </PathGeometry>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <UserControl.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingPath Storyboard.TargetName="Ellipse1"
                                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)"
                                  PathGeometry="{DynamicResource Daytona}"
                                  Duration="0:0:20" RepeatBehavior="Forever" Source="X" FillBehavior="Stop" />
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingPath Storyboard.TargetName="Ellipse1"
                                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)"
                                  PathGeometry="{StaticResource Daytona}"
                                  Duration="0:0:20" RepeatBehavior="Forever" Source="Y" FillBehavior="Stop" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
    </UserControl.Triggers>
    <Canvas Height="357" Name="Canvas1" Width="631">
        <Canvas.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/WpfCircuitLibrary;component/Images/Daytona2.png" />
        </Canvas.Background>
        <Ellipse Canvas.Left="292" Canvas.Top="328" Height="29" Name="Ellipse1" Stroke="Black" Width="29" Fill="#FF3DCA1F" />
        <Path Canvas.Left="12" Canvas.Top="12" Height="336" Name="Daytona" Data="{StaticResource Daytona}" Stroke="Black" Width="607" StrokeThickness="5" />

        <Button Content="Button" Height="30" Name="Button1" Width="92" DataContext="{Binding}" Canvas.Left="263" Canvas.Top="382" IsEnabled="{Binding}" />
    </Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Since I am not a programmer I do not know very well all command and sintax so that I have tried to look for any command allowing the Form button click to start The Element host but nothing and I looked for any command to link the two button s but ...nothing

Comment: Is your animation created in your Xaml or in VB.Net codebehind?

Comment: I started a new project so that I have my Form.vb and my Form [design].vb, I have then add to my project a WPF User Library in which I created an animation so that I have my UserControl.xaml.vb, I have my UserControl.xaml wrere i built my animation.

Comment: I have then add an elementhost to my Form and put the animation with its button inside and if I use that button everything works.

Comment: But I want to start the animation within the Element host by a Form Button

Comment: I understand that, my question was is your animation created in the Xaml or in VB.Net. Is it a Storyboard or a Simple animation.

Answer (score 0):

The ElementHost Control is a Container for your Wpf UserControl, any public method that you create is accessable from the Windows.Form application. I would take the code that was in your userControls Button Click event and create a Public Sub then call that from your Windows Form's Button Click event. I am going to assume that you created the animation in your code behind.

**Windows Form Form1.vb**

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        UserControl11.runAnimation()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        UserControl11.runXamlStoryBoard()
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Wpf UserControl**

```
Imports System.Windows.Media.Animation
Imports System.Windows.Controls

Public Class UserControl1
    Public Sub runAnimation()
        Dim da As DoubleAnimation = New DoubleAnimation
        da.From = 30
        da.To = 100
        da.Duration = New Windows.Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
        da.AutoReverse = True
        Button1.BeginAnimation(Button.HeightProperty, da)
    End Sub
    Public Sub runXamlStoryBoard()
        Dim sb As Storyboard = CType(FindResource("growButton"), Storyboard)
        sb.Begin()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        runAnimation()
    End Sub
```

End Class

**UserControl1.Xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="116" d:DesignWidth="246">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="growButton">
            <DoubleAnimation
                Storyboard.TargetName="Button1"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                From="30"
                To="100"
                Duration="0:0:1"
                RepeatBehavior="4x" />
        </Storyboard>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="Button1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="75" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

---

Here is a working example of what you are wanting. I moved your Storyboard into the UserControl.Resources so a x:Key can be assigned so it is available in the CodeBehind. I then referenced in you Trigger as a Static Resource.

**UserControl1.xaml"

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" Height="372" Width="640">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <PathGeometry x:Key="Daytona">
            <PathFigure IsClosed="True" StartPoint="290,320">
                <ArcSegment Point="290,320" Size="10,10" SweepDirection="Counterclockwise"></ArcSegment>
                <ArcSegment Point="430,250" Size="200,75"></ArcSegment>
                <ArcSegment Point="400,225" Size="30,25"></ArcSegment>
                <ArcSegment Point="370,215" Size="200,200" SweepDirection="Clockwise" ></ArcSegment>
                <ArcSegment Point="320,207" Size="150,200"></ArcSegment>
                <BezierSegment Point1="305,207" Point2="230,200" Point3="295,175"></BezierSegment>
                <ArcSegment Point="420,175" Size="570,500" SweepDirection="Clockwise"></ArcSegment>
                <BezierSegment Point1="437,177" Point2="452,162" Point3="462,152"></BezierSegment>
                <BezierSegment Point1="470,140" Point2="555,75" Point3="527,140"></BezierSegment>
                <ArcSegment Point="455,210" Size="500,500" SweepDirection="Clockwise"></ArcSegment>
                <BezierSegment Point1="445,220" Point2="450,280" Point3="545,220"></BezierSegment>
                <ArcSegment Point="480,18" Size="120,115"></ArcSegment>
                <ArcSegment Point="270,17" Size="520,100"></ArcSegment>
                <BezierSegment Point1="260,17" Point2="250,15" Point3="228,34"></BezierSegment>
                <BezierSegment Point1="218,34" Point2="200,33" Point3="180,20"></BezierSegment>
                <ArcSegment Point="40,220" Size="140,121"></ArcSegment>
                <ArcSegment Point="290,320" Size="690,600"></ArcSegment>
            </PathFigure>
        </PathGeometry>

        <Storyboard x:Key="MyPathAnimation">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingPath Storyboard.TargetName="Ellipse1"
                                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)"
                                 PathGeometry="{DynamicResource Daytona}"
                                  Duration="0:0:20" RepeatBehavior="Forever" Source="X" FillBehavior="Stop" />
            <DoubleAnimationUsingPath Storyboard.TargetName="Ellipse1"
                                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)"
                                 PathGeometry="{StaticResource Daytona}"
                                  Duration="0:0:20" RepeatBehavior="Forever" Source="Y" FillBehavior="Stop" />
        </Storyboard>

    </UserControl.Resources>
    <UserControl.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MyPathAnimation}" />
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
    </UserControl.Triggers>
    <Canvas Height="357" Name="Canvas1" Width="631">
        <Canvas.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/WpfCircuitLibrary;component/Images/Daytona2.png" />
        </Canvas.Background>
        <Ellipse Canvas.Left="292" Canvas.Top="328" Height="29" Name="Ellipse1" Stroke="Black" Width="29" Fill="#FF3DCA1F" />
        <Path Canvas.Left="12" Canvas.Top="12" Height="336" Name="Daytona" Data="{StaticResource Daytona}" Stroke="Black" Width="607" StrokeThickness="5" />
        <Button Content="Button" Height="30" Name="Button1" Width="92" DataContext="{Binding}" Canvas.Left="263" Canvas.Top="382" IsEnabled="{Binding}" />
    </Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

**UserControl1.Xaml.vb**

```
Imports System.Windows.Media.Animation

Public Class UserControl1
    Public Sub runPathAnimation()
        Dim sb As Storyboard = CType(FindResource("MyPathAnimation"), Storyboard)
        sb.Begin()
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Form1**

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        UserControl11.runPathAnimation()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I start to understand, but i have a path animation      <UserControl.Resources>
        <PathGeometry x:Key="Daytona">
            <PathFigure IsClosed="True" StartPoint ...etc I will try to work on it and see if i can make it work

Comment: @Ste Post your animation example to your question. I tried to give you a way of accessing it if you created it in the CodeBehind or in the Xaml.

Comment: ah! of course the<UserControl/>is missing from the code I put on the question,...forgot to copy it

Comment: Ok , I typed the code changine The name MyPathAnimation with my path name Daytona and this is the error coming out:Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Media.PathGeometry' to type 'System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard'.

Comment: I tried in my desperation to leave also the Path name as MyPathAnimation, but it can not find it

Comment: Tried also to change the type Stoyboard with Pathanimation in this line:Dim sb As Storyboard = CType(FindResource("Daytona"), Storyboard), but it says the that Begin() is not included in PathAnimation

Comment: @Ste use the usercontrol exactly the way that I posted it. I verified that it works

Comment: Sorry i didn't modify my XAML, You are right it works,...thank you so much for your help, if you are around Infineon Raceway When the Rolex Grand Am is there I am a Race car engineer following the Ferrari GT Program, You are officially invited to see the race. let me know if you would like it or not and Thank you so much

Comment: @Ste I am glad that it is working for you. I never know what part of the country I will be in at any specific point time, so I probably won't take you up on your kind offer even though it is in my backyard, but it is sincerly appreciated.